# Can't show graphic layer after add Turf in arcgis JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geojson, arcgis-js-api, turfjs

I want to make a curved by the line, but the code isn't working out. I use Turf.js to make bezier line.

```javascript
var line = {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "stroke": "#f00"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [-76.091308, 18.427501],
              [-76.695556, 18.729501],
              [-76.552734, 19.40443],
              [-74.61914, 19.134789],
              [-73.652343, 20.07657],
              [-73.157958, 20.210656]
            ]
          }
        };
        var curved = turf.bezier(line);
        var bg = new Graphic(curved, basicSymbol, {}, null);

        graphicsLayer.add(bg);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArcGIS API doesn't support drawing bezier lines.

References:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polyline.html
- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/polyline-amd.html

Comment: I see, so it doesn't support bezier. So I'll use SVG then.